# Enable shared from this variadic template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Basically I have a variadic class that works nice except the "enable shared from this" part.

```
template <typename S>
class Test;

template <typename... Args>
class Test < void( Args...)>: 

        public std::enable_shared_from_this
        < Test< void(Args...)> >
{

    public:
        std::shared_ptr< Test< void( Args...)>> getptr();

};

template <typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr< Test< void( Args...)>>  Test < void( Args...)>::getptr(){
    return shared_from_this(); // error here!
}
```

I get this error:

```
there are no arguments to 'shared_from_this' that depend on a template parameter, 
so a declaration of 'shared_from_this' must be available [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: Looks like you haven't applied the CRTP correctly: `std::enable_shared_from_this< Test< Args...> >` -> `std::enable_shared_from_this< Test< void(Args...) > >`

Comment: The code looks mutilated. For example, there are a few `class` keywords missing, at least.

Comment: just copy -paste typo for transition to stackoverflow. I was in hurry and did'nt pay too much attention. So I was missing "this->".. fixed:)

Comment: @DarioOO Now, kind suggestion: you could have wasted at least ~20 minutes of your helper's time less if you had the question properly. If you like to receive answers, you'll want to improve your question before posting, next time. Thank you.

Comment: @sehe: Sorry but connection was lagging and dynamic syntax highlight was not working properly. I had to see the answer posted for detect typos, I never expected that an answer was already there when I finished reloading the page, and anyway I never expected someone else would downvote the question for that, ok it needed to be improved, but I did that in minutes anyway ...

Comment: @DarioOO You're not helping yourself. "_just copy -paste typo for transition to stackoverflow. I was in hurry and did'nt pay too much attention_". Enough said. And "_within minutes_" was 25 minutes. (If you don't expect answers, why post? In general questions get the most attentinon _immediately_ after they're first posted). I was just saying. Use to advantage. Don't sulk. Next time you'll do better. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need

```
return this->shared_from_this();
```

(assuming that the rest is just typos, which is likely given the error message you received. You obviously need to derive from `std::enable_shared_from_this< Test< void(Args...)> >`)

Comment: yes that was a series of typo. basically I was missing only "this" thx!

Answer (score 3):

There are several typos in your code:

- <strike>You're missing the class-key (`struct` or `class`)</strike> (fixed now)
- <strike>the CRTP has to be fixed</strike> (fixed now)
- `shared_from_this` is a not a dependent name, but the base class (`enable_shared_from_this`) is, and therefore the name is not looked up in this base class scope when using non-dependent unqualified lookup (as in `shared_from_this()`). You need to make the lookup either qualified or dependent for this member function to be found.

Compiling example:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename S>
class Test;

template <typename... Args>
class Test < void( Args...)>
    : public std::enable_shared_from_this < Test<void(Args...)> >
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr< Test<void( Args...)> > getptr();
};

template <typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr< Test<void(Args...)> >  Test<void(Args...)> :: getptr()
{
    return this->shared_from_this(); // `this` makes the lookup dependent
    // alternatively:
    // return std::enable_shared_from_this< Test<void(Args...)> >
    //        ::shared_from_this();
}

int main()
{
    auto x = std::make_shared< Test<void(int)> >();
    x->getptr();
}
```